# How to show $0 in edit running total in crystal report when using condition?

Tags: crystal-reports

editing running total i use condition equal to true or false.

it is normal that it is blank in report,

but do not know how to show $0 when it is null and where to add formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create formula field
iif(condition, something, 0)